# Unable to show Milli seconds in X axis Stock Amcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I'm creating an amchart with a Date on X axis and certain value on the Y axis. The dataset contains date in JavaScript timestamp for example `1489635251118`. But I'm unable to plot the milli seconds on the axis. It only shows the date up to seconds. Milli seconds is not displayed. X axis is displayed as 11:50:30.

Here is a [DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWraoE) where I'm using categoryAxesSettings->minPeriod set to `fff`. It works fine.

```
 "categoryAxesSettings": {
     "minPeriod": "fff"
  }
```

But when I create new `dateFormats` it doesn't work. ([DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqoxaP))

```
"categoryAxesSettings": {
    "minPeriod": "qq",
    "dateFormats":[{
      "period":"qq",
      "format":"JJ:NN:SS:QQ"
     }]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second categoryAxesSettings snippet has a couple of bugs.

1) milliseconds for [`minPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxesSettings#minPeriod) is `"fff"`, not `qq`. The identifiers for format strings are different from the minPeriod identifiers.

2) Your [`dateFormats`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxis#dateFormats) must contain the full array of periods, even if you're not customizing them. This also applies to your [`categoryBalloonDateFormats`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/ChartCursorSettings#categoryBalloonDateFormats) array in your `chartCursorSettings`. The full array is also listed in the [formatting dates](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/formatting-dates/) documentation. The `period` must also match up against the list of allowable periods in `minPeriod` (again, `"qq"` is invalid):

```
"dateFormats": [{
  "period": "fff",
  "format": "NN:SS:QQQ"
}, {
  "period": "ss",
  "format": "NN:SS:QQQ"
}, {
  "period": "mm",
  "format": "JJ:NN"
}, {
  "period": "hh",
  "format": "JJ:NN"
}, {
  "period": "DD",
  "format": "MMM DD"
}, {
  "period": "WW",
  "format": "MMM DD"
}, {
  "period": "MM",
  "format": "MMM"
}, {
  "period": "YYYY",
  "format": "YYYY"
}]
```

I modified your code and added some more data so you can get a clearer picture [here](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/d44a3c300ebff2028d202b4aed468c1e/?editors=0010).